# How i can specifying the HTTP server address and port together?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Dhttp.port doesn't work in Play Framework 2.0?

I tried to start the server on the 1234 port, as it is written in example.
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ProductionConfiguration

So, i launch the play console and wrote the following command:

```
$ start -Dhttp.port=1234
```

Then i received the following response:

```
(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background)

Play server process ID is 6507
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 9000...
```

An application run on 9000 port. This is bug?

I know that i can use

```
$ start 1234
```

without http.port, but in this case i can't specify http.address together with the port, as it is written in the documentation.

```
$ start 1234                                        (WORK)
$ start -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1                    (WORK)
$ start -Dhttp.port=1234 -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1   (DOESN'T WORK)
$ start 1234 -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1               (DOESN'T WORK)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: And what about `start -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1 1234` ?

Comment: This is also don't work.

Comment: I opened a bug. https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/284-dhttpport-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's fixed in master branch.

You can get it from source:
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/BuildingFromSource